# Backup compression on MS SQL Web Edition 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My organization is looking into using MS SQL Web Edition 2008 R2, by SPLA, on our virtual server.
Currenty we are using MS SQL Express Edition 2008 R2.
Looking at the features table of different MS SQL 2008 R2 editions, one of the things that Web Edition does not support and we need, is Backup compression.
Currently, since we use Express, all of our DBs are under 10 GB.
We do nightly full backup of each data base to a storage drive.
My concern is, that once the DB sizes will grow after we start using Web Edition, the backup time will start to grow segnificantly.
What is the best approach to handle large DBs backups on MS SQL Web Edition?
Is there a way / workaround to do a compression?

Comment: Anyone voting to move that to serverfault - it will get closed there because the OP asks for (a) a product recommendation and (b) is not professional, so not welcome to ask there.

Comment: I don't think he is inherently asking for a product. That is just one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to not take a full backup every day. Use differential backups almost every day (say, 6 out of 7 days a week) and do a full backup every so often (say, 1 day a week). The differentials should be significantly smaller than your full assuming that you don't have a lot of data churn going on in your database.

Comment: I've never used differential backups in MS SQL. How can I tell if this is a good solution for us? We do many record updates everydate and add about 400,000 rows to a history table (per day) in some of the DBs

Comment: I'd say just implement it. You won't affect your recoverability by doing so and you can see how big your differentials will be with respect to your fulls.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy a third-party backup software for SQL Server. It is an incremental cost over the SQL Server license.

Or you could try to backup to a compressed NTFS folder.

Or you backup uncompressed and compress with 7-Zip which uses state-of-the-art compression algorithms that compress to a much smaller size than SQL Server does.

Comment: regarding 7-zip, there are several problems with it: 1. I will need to write a software which takes the uncompressed backup, compress it and deletes the uncompressed file. 2. the time it will take to do uncompressed backup can be long for large DB. 3. I will have to always make sure that there is enough disk space to contain the uncompressed backup. Regarding third-party, Can you recommand third-party backup software for SQL Server?

Comment: @LimS I do not have a recommendation but the vendors are easy to find. They usually have a proprietary format and might lock you in.

Comment: Although my comment is late it may be useful to someone reading it afterwards. Although statements 2 and 3 are correct this is not so for 1. You use batch files with Task Scheduler to achieve compression, copying  and deletion of backup files